# What does %1|%2 mean in a shell open command?

Tags: registry, clickonce, windows-shell, shellexecute

For example, Clickonce application reference (`.appref-ms`) files have this registry entry:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Application.Reference\shell\open\command]
@="rundll32.exe dfshim.dll,ShOpenVerbShortcut %1|%2"
```

This presents two challenges:

1. What is the value of the second replacement (there's only one file)
2. Use of the pipe character makes it difficult to test things in the command prompt.

I've searched the rest of the classes hive and this appears to be the only usage of such a construct on my system.

These don't work (from the command prompt), with or without quotes:

- `rundll32.exe dfshim.dll,ShOpenVerbShortcut FileNameInCurrentDir.appref-ms`
- `rundll32.exe dfshim.dll,ShOpenVerbShortcut C:\Path\To\File.appref-ms`
- `rundll32.exe dfshim.dll,ShOpenVerbShortcut file://c:/Path/To/File.appref-ms`
- `rundll32.exe dfshim.dll,ShOpenVerbShortcut "file:///c:/Path/To/File.appref-ms"`

Resulting in various errors:

- `Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.`
- `Invalid URI: The URI scheme is not valid.`
- `Exception reading manifest from file:///c:/Path/To/File.appref-ms: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.`

Answer (score 1):

The pipe character is an argument delimiter. So `rundll32.exe dfshim.dll,ShOpenVerbShortcut %1|%2` means: run `ShOpenVerbShortcut` from `dfshim.dll` with arguments `%1` and `%2`.

I have noticed two uses of this: in printto menus and with appref-ms.

Comment: what would the 2 arguments be? And how are they passed?

Comment: The attributes are context dependant, for example in printto one arg is what to print and the second is the printer name. Did not find any info on how the arguments are escaped, but it looks like everything except the `|` characted is passed through without changes (for example full paths with unicode characters and spaces in them worked)

Comment: No idea what's the second argument in appref-ms.